# Why is my CPU maxing out when I set to use GPU rendering?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I am using blender 3.4.1

Does the GPU bring no value in faster rendering? Is there anything that could be done to render faster?

I have updated the drivers to use the Nvidia Studio drivers. The graphics card also has 16G of local ram.

[image]

I have also tried using some of the benchmark animation files from the blender site, including both the fluid simulation and the lava simulation.
I included my simple file fir debugging as well if that helps at all. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hmH67DdnK9JAfWEXEW4fkN8FgknCRLJL/view?usp=sharing

I have OptiX (I have also tried CUDA) NVIDA GeForce RTX 4080 selected in preference and render engine = cycles, Feature Set = supported and Device = GPU Compute. It is taking ridiculously longer than when the CPU was rendering, yet the CPU is getting maxed when trying to GPU render.

[image]

So I did run the benchmark and it does appear that the GPU is faster but when compared against the average for a 4080, my 2k, 2k, and 4k values are alot lower than the 9k average. Is there something else I could be doing incorrectly?

[image]

Comment: RTX Uses cuda cores and should be noticeably faster than CPU rendering alone. This may be a hardware issue on your end. I downloaded your scene and GPU rendering took around 35 seconds while CPU rendering took nearly a minute.

Comment: It's literally a brand new computer so it wouldn't make sense to me if it was a hardware issue, when you rendered the file, does that mean you had the exact same settings too? If you change anything can you list them

Comment: Note that task manager won't report usage for rt cores, and the cpu will always see utilization even when handing tasks to the gpu

Comment: That's fair I've also seen mentions of that, and that applying cuda as one of the GPU dropdowns might report more but regardless, as mentioned by callmepro, his render was at 35 seconds while mine got a few frames in after about five-ten minutes which can't be right at all

Comment: I should clarify that was render times for an individual frame. The only settings I changed was to switch on the usage of GPU and CPU in Blender Preferences > System.